# The icon and the Text in the button are not totally visible+I want to know the name of upload's icon React native

Tags: react-native

I'm working on react native project ,I'm creating icon Button with text, the text and the icon are not totally visible and I want to know the name of upload's icon :

[image: So this is the screenshot that shows my problem:]

I'm using Button from react-native-elements:

```
import {Button} from 'react-native-elements';
```

This is the code of the button +style :

```
<Button
          icon={{
//I want the name of the upload's icon 
            //name: ,
            size: 15,
            color: 'white',
          }}
          title="Upload Signature"
          buttonStyle={{
            backgroundColor: '#e88720',
            
            marginLeft: 50,
            marginRight: 0,
            height: 30,
            width: 150,
          }}
          containerStyle={{
            height: 30,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            marginHorizontal: 20,
          }}
          titleStyle={{
            fontSize: 11,
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            marginTop: 0,
            padding: 9,
            textAlign: 'center',
          }}
        />
```

Comment: Refer [this](https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/) to search for any required icon.

Comment: I need to add a specific style to the button so that the content of the button comes up

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for solutions too but decided to remove the height on both the buttonStyle and the containerStyle and it was alot better.

```
<Button
  disabledStyle={{
    backgroundColor: '#cecece90',
  }}
  disabledTitleStyle={{
    color: '#000',
  }}
  buttonStyle={{
    width: isLoadingAddress ? 130 : 90,
    height: 30,
    borderRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderColor: '#fff',
  }}
  containerStyle={{
    margin: 5,
    marginLeft: 25,
    borderColor: '#1874FF',
  }}
  titleStyle={{
    width: '100%',
    fontSize: 16,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    color: colors.secondary,
    fontFamily: 'Sen-Bold',
  }}
  title={isLoadingAddress ? 'Fetching...' : 'Submit'}
  type="clear"
  disabled={
    !inputAddress.trim() || isLoading
  }
  onPress={() => _onSubmitAddress()}
/>
```